# Link that looks like an image button doesn't listen to color: instruction in css

Tags: html, css

I have a page at [http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php](http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=49), 
and you see on the bottom-right I have a teal image.  It is really a link and in that link I can't seem to get the text color to appear white.

Here is my CSS:

```
.button 
{
  display: block;
  background: #4E9CAF;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:button.visited 
{
  display: block;
  background: #4E9CAF;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

and here is how I make the link with HTML:

```
<a class="button" id="follow_problem" href="#" title="...">Follow Problem</a>
```

Any idea what is going wrong and why the color of the link isn't white?

Comment: Oh, this `a:button.visited` should be `a:visited.button` instead, no? That is: an anchor which is `:visited` and `.button`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `a:link` (line 95) is more specific than `.button` (line 109).

You can fix it by changing the rule to

```
.button,
a:link.button {
    /* rules */
}
```

Tips:

- While using `!important` will work, it is a silly workaround that will eventually get you in trouble, and it is actually a misuse - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules
- Use `Firebug` for Firefox, or Chrome's `inspect element`, to check the css affecting a given element.

Comment: thank you that worked..except the background of the button is white in IE - any idea why that may be the case?

Comment: The `filter: ...;` property from `.button` does not seem to be overriden by `a:link.button`. So it remains. I guess resetting the `filter: ...;` property in `a:link.button` would fix it. HTH

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you're trying to override the styling of the `a:link` class Try:

**Option 1:**

Here is the class you're trying to override:

```
a:link {
    color: #3686A7;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

You need to add `!important` to the end of your style declaration:

```
.button {
    color: white !important;
}
```

**Option 2:**

You could further define the `a:link` class rules:

```
a:link.button {
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `.button` class, use this: `color: white !important;`. The problem happens because the `a` style declaration is applied after the `.button` declaration, in effect cancelling the color you have set in favor of the link 's color property. Using `!important` ensures the `color` rule is applied over any other.

Comment: Unless that other is also `!important`. You are advocating misuse of `!important`.

Comment: My understanding of http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order is that since `!important` disrupts the normal cascading order, it should only be used when this disruption is meant. Otherwise you risk ruining usability for the users. As such, I think your suggestion is not a good practice - sorry that I wasn't clear in my first comment.

Comment: As per the "vote hunting" part of your comment. Should I stop being part of the community just because I provided an answer? I'm not hunting for upvotes: I +1'd @JamesHill, -1'd a now-deleted answer that ruined other links by changing the style on `a:link`, and did not vote for the other ones as I felt they did not deserve neither upvotes nor downvotes. If you want we can discuss this further, or you can flag me for moderator attention.

Comment: @ANeves, not so. The disruption IS meant, to disambiguate between two conflicting style rules, so the use of `!important` is, IMHO, perfectly valid.

Comment: I don't see ambiguity or conflict, I see the concept of specificity working as per the spec. But I also see that I was confusing the cascading order - author normal and important declarations stand in adjacent levels, so using `!important` should not affect user declarations. I apologise. +1 I guess, and to @archil in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have another class in common_elements.css that has higher priority than .button

```
a:link 
{
    color: #3686A7;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Try making your .button more prioritized by `!important`